# Bounty not received even after grace period end

Tags: support, bug, bug-reporting-process

I have added the answer to this question of which the bounty and grace period has ended, but I still didn't get any points.

Question link: [click here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69756814/run-custom-script-after-docker-container-startup/69820852#69820852)

I got all the upvotes before the bounty ended.

The answer has three *upvotes*.

> If you do not award your bounty within 7 days (plus the grace period),
> the highest voted answer created after the bounty started with a
> minimum score of 2 will be awarded half the bounty amount (or the full
> amount, if the answer is also accepted). If two or more eligible
> answers have the same score (their scores are tied), the oldest answer
> is chosen. If there's no answer meeting those criteria, no bounty is
> awarded to anyone.

The document stated half should be there.

Comment: So, if that answer is right, you should expect the bounty (at half value) in about 31 minutes.

Comment: The bounty went to [the oldest answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69815329/2821954) because at that time the score was tied at 2 (can be cross-checked on each profile's reputation timing).

Comment: yes you are right however when i posted question i had 3 vopte but suddenly bounty went to older answer and someone down vote to answer.

Comment: The Downvote on your answer was given today, @HarshManvar , @ 12:58:58Z. The bounty was awarded at 13:02; 4 minutes *prior* to the bounty being awarded. This might have been due to the meta effect, it might have been someone just found it not useful; we won't know unless the downvoter expresses their reasons, and that is unlikely as it's not required.

Comment: yes you are right might be due to meta effect